# How to get the jQuery tabs to work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am working from this example:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

and trying to get the tabs to work like they look on this wireframe or at least close: http://problemio.com/wireframe.pdf

What I have so far is this query:

```
$(function()
{
          $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
          ...
```

and this html:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">First Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third Tab</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>First tab stuff</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Second tab stuff</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Third tab stuff</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But for some reason this doesn't work at all and just shows the tabls as links that don't do anything.  I am importing this js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any Tabs in the wireframe, or don't recognise them

Comment: @HerrSerker thats because they look like links :) saying "tab 1, tab 2, tab 3"

Comment: Where is your css for all of this ?

Comment: Maybe your code isn't called at all. try an alert(1) before the call to tabs() and see, if the alert is executed.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder the css for the whole site or just the tabs?

Comment: @GeekedOut I mean, in the wireframe PDF not in the code

Comment: Geeked Out, for jquery ui in general, it can't style them without the CSS.

Comment: jjclarkson i guess jquery is wrong too then ? :-P http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/default.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be missing the CSS. Try to include

http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css

Comment: adding that line gave an error message for unexpected token. Here is what I added: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css"></script>

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">`  or
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">`

Comment: It's a stylesheet! Not a script!

Answer (score 3):

Already experienced this issue myself. In my case, I'd forgot to add the css references for the jquery UI plugin. You don't seem to be adding them either.

Could you doublecheck if you have included the css? You should be able to use googleapis CDN - for example:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
```

Here you will find the list of available themes: [JQuery-UI Blog - v1.8.16](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2011/08/jquery-ui-1-8-16/). They also provide links to the various available CDN locations (the above link was taken from there).